Beat frequency - Square signal
This question comes from this one, LTspice - Beat frequency:
It appears that when I did a FFT of two sinusoidal signals, there was no what is called beat frequency.
When I do the same exercice with two square signals, it appers a beat frequency... But I still do not understand why there is a beat frequency if we think a square signal as a sum of sinusoids. If there was no beat frequency when I was using two single sinusoids, why there would be a beat frequency with two square signals?
Here is the simulation:

Here is the result:

I do not think that it is a problem of simulation precision. It cannot be a simple coincidence to see a frequency equal to f1-f2 on the fft graph? Does anyone know the math behond this result?

See my comments in the original question. I was able to get a "beat" when I replicated your circuit, but when I decreased the max time step in the simulation parameters down to be well below 1/f, the beat goes away.

Hi, MrGerber I know that the maximum time step has an influence on the result as it makes the number of points higher or lower. I the case of the above simulation, the minimum time step is 10 ps which is very low. So I hope that the error ar very low but apparently there is still some errors...

I'd say the result you got for the two sine waves is logical: you can only create new frequencies using nonlinear operations, and addition is a linear operation. So, a beat frequency can't arise from anything.
You're also not seeing a beat frequency in your square wave example when you just add them up linearly. Mathematically still impossible.
If you did a continuous-time Fourier transform of the sum of the two square waves, you would of course just see the addition of both their transforms. If the square waves' frequencies are rationally related, then there will be an infinite series of frequencies where both square waves have harmonics. You might notice a few that stand out, namely when these combine constructively.
However, you're not doing that: you are first sampling your signal with a finite bandwidth, meaning that there's an infinite amount of signals that have the same samples as yours (so, here you're losing information on your square waves actually being square waves), and then you take a finite amount of samples (an FFT length) and do an FFT of that. This will of course lead to aliasing, and alternating, potentially surprising frequency components.
So, this is just an artefact of you assuming properties on your analysis that it doesn't have.

Thank you for your comment ! "You might notice a few that stand out, namely when these combine constructively." What do you mean by harmonics that combine constructively ? Does it means that 2 harmonics can give birth to an other harmonic ?

no. I explicitly said that can't happen. I said they construcively add up. That's all I said. Their magnitude gets higher.

Ok thank you for your help :)

Made with microcap v12
The text in the picture shows the "equivalence" of the 2 formulas.

